# range and basis of range of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let T: $P_2 \to \mathbb R ^2$ be a linear transformation define by $$ T(a+bx+cx^2) = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a-b \\
    b+c \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
I'm trying to figure out the range(T) and its basis. From a search online I found the range is the column space, i.e all possible linear combinations of its column vectors. So

> $range(T)$ = {$\vec w$  $\vert$  $T (\vec p)$ = $\vec w$}

\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
Is the only one I can come up with. Can someone explain the process in finding any others in the basis (if they exist)?

Comment: Upto isomorphism, this map is equivalent to the map $\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^2$ defined by $X\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&0\\0&1&1\end{pmatrix}X$. Now, do you know how to find the range and basis of a matrix transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$T(a+bx+cx^2) = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a-b \\
    b+c \\
    \end{pmatrix}= a\begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}+ b\begin{pmatrix}
    -1 \\
    1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}+ c\begin{pmatrix}
    0\\
    1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

then we can conclude that the range is $\mathbb R ^2$.

Comment: I see, thus the basis is \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix} and \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix} ?

Comment: @undergrad Yes of course. Note that it is A basis not THE basis. For example also (1,0) and (-1,1) is a basis as any other pairs of linearly independent vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

In the standard basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$ of $P_2$, the polynomial $a+bx+cx^2$ has components $(a,b,c)^T$, and your transformation is represented bi the matrix:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&-1&0\\
0&1&1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a\\b\\c
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
a-b\\
b+c
\end{pmatrix}
$$

can you fin the rank of the matrix and a basis for its range?